# Cluster centers have different dimensionality in Spark MLlib

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, k-means, apache-spark-ml

I use Spark 2.0.2. I have data which is partitioned by day. I want to cluster the different partitions independent from each other and than compare the cluster centers (calculate distance between them) to see, how the clusters would change over time.

I do exactly the same preprocessing (scaling, one hot encoding, etc.) for every partition. I use a predefined pipeline for this which works perfectly in "normal" learning and prediction contexts. But when I want to calculate the distance between the cluster centers, the corresponding vectors of the different partitions have a different size (different dimensionality).

Some code snippets:

The preprocessing pipeline is built like this:

```scala
val protoIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("protocol").setOutputCol("protocolIndexed").setHandleInvalid("skip")
val serviceIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("service").setOutputCol("serviceIndexed").setHandleInvalid("skip")
val directionIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("direction").setOutputCol("directionIndexed").setHandleInvalid("skip")

val protoEncoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("protocolIndexed").setOutputCol("protocolEncoded")
val serviceEncoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("serviceIndexed").setOutputCol("serviceEncoded")
val directionEncoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("directionIndexed").setOutputCol("directionEncoded")

val scaleAssembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("duration", "bytes", "packets", "tos", "host_count", "srv_count")).setOutputCol("scalableFeatures")
val scaler = new StandardScaler().setInputCol("scalableFeatures").setOutputCol("scaledFeatures")
val featureAssembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("scaledFeatures", "protocolEncoded", "urgent", "ack", "psh", "rst", "syn", "fin", "serviceEncoded", "directionEncoded")).setOutputCol("features")
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(protoIndexer, protoEncoder, serviceIndexer, serviceEncoder, directionIndexer, directionEncoder, scaleAssembler, scaler, featureAssembler))
pipeline.write.overwrite().save(config.getString("pipeline"))
```

Define k-means, load predefined preprocessing-pipeline, add k-means to the pipeline:

```scala
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(40).setTol(1.0e-6).setFeaturesCol("features")
val pipelineStages = Pipeline.load(config.getString("pipeline")).getStages
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(pipelineStages ++ Array(kmeans))
```

Load data partitions, calculate features, fit pipeline, get k-means model and show size of the first cluster center as example:

```scala
(1 to 7 by 1).map { day =>
  val data = sparkContext.textFile("path/to/data/" + day + "/")
  val rawFeatures = data.map(extractFeatures....).toDF(featureHeaders: _*)
  val model = pipeline.fit(rawFeatures)

  val kmeansModel = model.stages(model.stages.size - 1).asInstanceOf[KMeansModel]
  println(kmeansModel.clusterCenters(0).size)
}
```

For the different partitions, the cluster centers have different dimensions (But the same for every of the 40 clusters within a partition). So I can't calculate the distance between them. I would suspect that they are all of equal size (namely the size of my euclidean space which is 13, because I have 13 features). But it gives my weird numbers which I don't understand.

I saved the extracted feature vectors to a file to check them. Their format is as suspected. Every feature is present.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or if I have a misunderstanding? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping over the fact that [KMeans is not a good choice for processing categorical data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/24) your code doesn't guarantee:

- The same index - feature relationship between batches. `StringIndexer` assigns labels following frequencies. The most common string is encoded as 0, the least common one as a `numLabels` - 1.
- The same number of inidces between batches, and as a result the same shape of one-hot-encoded and assembled vectors. Size of the vector is equal to the number of unique labels adjusted depending on the value of `dropLast` parameter in `OneHotEncoder`.

In consequence encoded vectors may have different dimensions and interpretation from batch to batch.

If you want consistent encoding you'll need persistent dictionary mapping which ensure consistent indexing between batches.